# How do i get the last file from directory by the file name and then create the next file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the loop i'm using today:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTime.Count; i++)
{
  string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
  link = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + selectedregion + "&time=" + result + "&ir=" +
                           infraredorvisual;
  string filePath = Path.Combine(satimagesdir, "SatImage" + (i + last) + ".GIF");
  try
  {
     client1.DownloadFile(link, filePath);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      DannyGeneral.Logger.Write(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

This way now i'm not getting the last file and the variable last is not in use so it's all the time 0 so in the end it will allways create new 0 to 8 files and will overwrite existing files.

What i need to do is two things:

1. To find the last file by name by it's part of the number like i explained above.
2. The next new 9 files should be by the numbers from the last file.

So if i know for example that the last existing file is SatImage845.gif then the next file i know should be SatImage846.gif and then i need to make that in the loop it will create SatImage846.gif,SatImage846.gif....untill SatImage854.gif

This should be the rule.

Each time the loop should create the next 9 files according to the last file name.

Comment: I don't understand what your actual technical problem is; but at some level you should be using System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() then sort the resultant list of files, deconstruct your file name, extract the numerical value, add one to it, and voila ! you have your new file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this before your `for` loop, so `last` is the highest number of the files in that same directory.

```
        var regex = new Regex("SatImage([0-9]+).gif", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var last =
            Directory.GetFiles(satimagesdir)
                .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                .Select(x => regex.Match(x))
                .Where(x => x.Success)
                .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                .First();
```